# Need help concatenating column names

Tags: r, concatenation

I am generating 5 different prediction and adding those predictions to an existing data frame.  My code is:

```
For j in i{
…
actual.predicted <- data.frame(test_data, predicted)
}
```

I am trying to concatenate words together to create new column names, in the loop.  Specifically, I have a column named “predicted” and I am generating predictions in each iteration of the loop.  So, in the first iteration, I want the new column name to be “predicted.1” and for the second iteration, the new column name should be “predicted.2” and so on.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may not even need to use a loop here, but assuming you do, one pattern which might work well here would be to use a list:

```
results <- list()
for j in i {
    # do something involving j
    name <- paste0("predicted.", j)
    results[[name]] <- data.frame(test_data, predicted)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your insights.  This is so far off from what Imwas thinking!

Comment: @KevinEDow Well you showed us 3 lines of code, and no data, so what were you expecting?

Comment: the code was not really relevant to dynamically changing the column names by concatenating the alue of j.  Your suggestion of name <- paste0(“predicted.”, j) was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the names after assigning new columns

```
actual.predicted <- data.frame(orig_col = sample(10))
for (j in 1:5){
  new_col = sample(10)
  actual.predicted <- cbind(actual.predicted, new_col)
  names(actual.predicted)[length(actual.predicted)] <- paste0('predicted.',j)
}

actual.predicted
#    orig_col predicted.1 predicted.2 predicted.3 predicted.4 predicted.5
# 1         1           4           4           9           1           5
# 2        10           2           3           7           5           9
# 3         8           6           5           4           2           3
# 4         5           9           9          10           7           7
# 5         2           1          10           8           3          10
# 6         9           7           6           6           8           6
# 7         7           8           7           2           4           2
# 8         3           3           1           1           6           8
# 9         6          10           2           3           9           4
# 10        4           5           8           5          10           1
```

Comment: Wow...you did in 1 line what I just did in 4.  I am so humbled by what I am learning from this community.  I now see that I have a lot to learn.